# Unable to navigate correctly with back button in WIndows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am making a universal App for the Windows Store and Windows Phone Store. My phone version has three menu screens the user can navigate to and from. Initially anytime I used the hardware back button, regardless of what page I was on, the app just closed. I then changed the back button navigation like this

Main Page:

```
public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;

    }
```

Game Menu Page (page 2)

```
public GameModes()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
    }


    void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

        if (rootFrame != null && rootFrame.CanGoBack)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            rootFrame.GoBack();
        }
    }
```

At this point everything is working as it should if the user presses the back button. However when I get to the 3rd page and try to go back out, it will go to page 2, then go to page 1 but then the app will not close by pressing the back button!

Page 3

```
 public TrialPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
        CountDownTimer();
    }

    void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(GameModes));
    }
```

Comment: Remember that *HardwareButtons.BackPressed* iss app-wide event. From what I see you are not unsubscribing from it. Try to debug your app, especially put breakpoints in those events, see what's going on.

Comment: How about moving the `HardwareButtons.BackPressed` subscription and handler to `MainPage` and remove it from the other pages?